# position not detected on tablet with wifi by LocationManager

Tags: android, geolocation, google-maps-android-api-2, android-wifi

I'm developing an application that uses google maps v2 for android.. i've tested my app in two smartphones (Alcatel 4030d and Samsung s4 mini) and in a tablet (acer iconia b1-a71).. in all three devices i've enabled the same android settings for the geolocation and the manifest of the app have all the necessary permissions.. The gps is disabled so the best provider is the network..
The problem is on the tablet : it says that the network provider is the best provider and, moreover, is enabled but doesn't download any data about the position

the location resulting from getLastKnownLocation method is null

Surprisingly, it works in the two smartphones but it doesn't in the tablet.. why?

Comment: I think acer iconia b1-a71 tablet does not have sim. so it will not give location based on network provider

Comment: yes, but i'm connected through wifi at home.. doesn't the network provider work also for classical internet connection??